# Keras Error using Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, keras

I've just started out with keras this week and have been going through the documentation to figure out why I'm getting an error. But I figured it would be faster if I got some help, and it feels like a detail that I'm just not seeing.

```
Error when checking model input: expected lambda_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (0, 1)
```

Here is the Entire Code to look over if that helps you see what I'm doing wrong.

```
import csv
import cv2
import numpy as np

lines = []
with open('../data2/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for line in reader:
                lines.append(line)
        for row in reader:
            steering_center = float(row[3])
                # create adjusted steering measurements for the side camera images
            correction = 0.2 # this is a parameter to tune
            steering_left = steering_center + correction
            steering_right = steering_center - correction
                 # read in images from center, left and right cameras
            directory = "..." # fill in the path to your training IMG directory
            img_center = process_image(np.asarray(Image.open(path + row[0])))
            img_left = process_image(np.asarray(Image.open(path + row[1])))
            img_right = process_image(np.asarray(Image.open(path + row[2])))
                # add images and angles to data set
            car_images.extend(img_center, img_left, img_right)
            steering_angles.extend(steering_center, steering_left, steering_right)

images = []
measurements =[]
for line in lines:
        source_path = line[0]
        filename = source_path.split('/')[-1]
        current_path = '../data2/IMG/' + filename
        image = cv2.imread(current_path)
        measurement = float(line[3])
        measurements.append(measurement)

augmented_images, augmented_measuremnets = [], []
for image, measurement in zip(image, measurements):
        augmented_images.append(image)
        augmented_measuremnets.append(measurement)
        augmented_images.append(cv2.flip(image,1))
        augmented_measuremnets.append(measurement*-1)

X_train = np.array(images)
y_train = np.array(measurements)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Lambda, Cropping2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(160,320,3)))
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((70,25), (0,0))))
model.add(Convolution2D(24,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(36,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(48,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=5)


model.save('model.h5')
exit()
```

I'm trying to figure out if I need to resize my input data set for this `model.fit(...)` function to work properly. It worked before without issues until I added the cropping and more data.

Thanks, any direction would help, even if it just gets me closer to understanding this dimensional error.

```
File "nvidia.py", line 64, in <module>
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=5)
      File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 672, in fit
        initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
      File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1117, in fit
        batch_size=batch_size)
      File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in _standardize_user_data
        exception_prefix='model input')
      File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 112, in standardize_input_data
        str(array.shape))
    ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected lambda_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to insert `image` into `images`. So `X_train` is basically empty.

Comment: You're right! I don't know how that got messed up... I did it on a previous model. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions was not the Lambda or in Keras it was me being foolish, somehow this model didn't get the line `images.append(image)` so the X_train array was not being populated. Problem solved.